# A Bad Charger Damaged My Asus TF300t Tablets

Tags: battery, charging

I bought a charger set off of Amazon.When i plugged it into my tablet it flashed and rebooted and the battery shows 0% and will not charge.Also when i hook up the USB charger the computer does not see it nor dose any screen pop up on my tablet.
I managed to mess up both tablets before i figured out it was the charger.

So I bought a different charger and USB data cable , still no good.Tried the trickle charge thing for 2 days still no good.

So Far i have bought a new fully charged battery ,same thing no good,replaced the charging/docking ribbon,still no good. Factory reset , no good.

I can boot with what battery i have left but it will not charge or go above 0%
always says "Connect Charger"

Is there any thing i can do or did the charger damage the board on the tablet?
Other than not charging or being seen by the USB everything else works.

Any feed back would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chinese "Colorfly", Android 4.4.2 similar case. Long press the "Power" button, select "Power off". Connect to USB or charger. Charging starts a couple minutes later - depends on discharge level.